# Backbone.Marionette / progressive model loading strategy

Tags: backbone.js, model, marionette, progressive-download

I'm working on an analytics-like dashboard with heavy data. Obviously waiting for all this data to come in isn't a good idea as it would increase load-times beyond acceptable lengths. My idea is to progressively add parts of data when certain `Controllers` instantiate a model. I imagine it'll end up looking something like this:

```
class List.Controller extends Marionette.Controller
  initialize: (options) ->
    { model } = options

    model.fetch( something here ) unless model.get('data')

    @showData model

  getDataView: (model) ->
    new List.Data {model}

  showData: (model) ->
    dataView = @getDataView model

    App.mainRegion.show dataView
```

I was wondering if someone has experience with this, and what a good strategy would be for what to pass into the fetch call and how to structure that...

Edit: to clarify, I'm looking for a scalable strategy to load more data for a model based on a get-param or a different endpoint when my app needs it. Should this be handled by methods on my model or by passing stuff into fetch for example?

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" way is having a pageable collection, such as [Backbone Pageable](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone-pageable)

Then you can have a CollectionView or CompositeView which will handle most of the work for you.